# How to add button to toolbar using Three20?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, three20, uitoolbar

I'm trying to use this to add button to toolbar:

```c
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];
    self.navigationController.toolbar.translucent = YES;
    self.navigationController.toolbar.barStyle    = UIBarStyleBlack;

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 10.0);

    UIBarButtonItem *infoButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

    NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:infoButton];

    [self.navigationController setToolbarItems:a];
}
```

But there is no button in toolbar when I started application! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting the navigation controllers `toolBarItems` property try setting it in the currently displayed view controller like so:

```
[self setToolbarItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:infoButton, nil]];
```

Also adding infoButton to the toolBarItems will automatically retain it. So remember to place

`[infoButton release]`;

at the bottom of your `viewWillAppear` method.